# multiple IF Calculation excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I currently have this formula in Excel:

```
=IF(G1+I1>E77,H1)
```

Sometimes I want it to be like this:

```
=IF(C1+E1>G1,D1)
```

I need both these formulas in the same cell but there will only ever be a figure in either  `C1` or `I1`.   Is there a way of automatically determining which of the two cells has the figure in it and using the correct formula ?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what the relevant part of your worksheet looks like? Would an `OR` statement work?

Comment: i am unable to post images yet as i am new user i will try OR statement, thanks still learning a lot .

Answer (score 1):

```
=IF(C1="",IF(G1+I1>E77,H1),IF(C1+E1>G1,D1))
```

Or possibly it should be:

```
=IF(C1="",IF((G1+I1)>E77,H1),IF((C1+E1)>G1,D1))
```

Comment: Nice example of nesting `IF`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would do

```
=IF(AND(C1, C1+E1>G1), D1, IF(AND(I1, G1+I1>E77), H1, " "))
```

What this will do is only check the inequalities if there is a value in the appropriate cell.  The " " will leave you a blank cell rather than a FALSE if both C1 and I1 are blank.